# Whether `Bloc` and `Cubit` are completely equivalent?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

Let's consider this case:

```dart
class Repository {
  final _controller = Behaviorsubject<List<Object>>();

  Stream<List<Object>> get stream => _controller.stream;

  void fetchObjects() async {
    final response = await _dataService.getObjects();
    final objects = _convertResponseToObjects();
    _controller.add(objects);
  }
}
```

```dart
class ObjectsBloc extends Bloc {
  ObjectsBloc(this._repository) : super(Status.initial) {
    _init();
  }

  final Repository _repository;

  void _init() {
    on<ObjectsFetched>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: Status.waiting));
      await emit.forEach<List<Object>>(
        _repository.stream,
        onData: (objects) => state.copyWith(
          status: Status.success,
          objects: objects,
        ),
        onError: (error, _) => state.copyWith(
          status: Status.failure,
          error: error,
        ),
      );      
    });
    add(const ObjectFetched());
  }
}
```

```dart
class ObjectsCubit extends Cubit {
  ObjectsCubit(this._repository) : super(Status.initial) {
    _init();
  }

  final Repository _repository;

  void _init() {
    _repository.stream.listen((objects) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        status: Status.success, 
        objects: objects,
      ));
    }, onError: (error, _) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        status: Status.failure, 
        error: error,
      ));
    });    
  }

  void fetchEntities() {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: Status.waiting));
    _repositoy.fetchEntities();
  }
}
```

Is the functionality of current `ObjectsBloc` and `ObjectsCubit` equivalent? Is there any benefit of using `await emit.forEach` in `ObjectsBloc` instead of `_repository.stream.listen` in `ObjectsCubit` to process `Status.success`?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: to answer specifically about `repository.stream.listen((...) => emit)` versus `emit.forEach((...) => repository.stream)`:

They are equivalent. In Bloc you could swap the two syntaxes. In Cubit though, `emit` is a function, not an `Emitter`, so you won't have access to `emit.forEach`.

---

**About the difference between Bloc and Cubit:**

They are pretty equivalent, the main difference between Bloc and Cubit lies in the event system.

**Cubit**

There is an interaction -> you call a function of the Cubit -> it updates the state. Basically you are telling your Cubit "hey, this just happened, please do that".

*Benefits*:

- less boilerplate, because you don't have to create as many events as you have interactions
- direct link between the widget and the logic ; events can sometimes look like spaghetti code

**Bloc**

There is an interaction -> you send an event to the Bloc -> it updates the state. Basically you are telling your Bloc "hey, this just happened, it's up to you what to do".

*Benefits*:

- logic is more like a black box since you don't have a direct dependency between the widget and the treatment
- you can apply Rx Observables to the event stream ; for example if you want to delay or throttle some treatment after user interaction

Comment: You just copy paste the documentation. Who bothers me to use RX on `_repository.stream` of `ObjectsCubit`?

Basically they both are telling `hey, this just happened, please do that`

_logic is more like a black box since you don't have a direct dependency between the widget and the treatment_

This is actually not clean what do you mean. What difference between `cubit.doThis()` and `bloc.add(DoThis())`? Right. no difference.

Comment: Semantically there is a difference. You call `cubit.doThis()` or `bloc.add(ThisHappened())` which results in the same treatment, but the concepts are different. In the first case, you know how the Cubit works so you call its function directly. In the second case you are not supposed to know how the Bloc works, so you just pass it an event and it is its responsibility to do the job. It is called separation of concern. And about Rx, it can be useful to throttle or delay user events, like typing in a text field, so you won't send an event for each individual typed character.

Comment: well I am not completely agree because if I create a cubit with method `selectTab` I know that it will selects a tab, if I create a bloc with event `TabSelected` I know it selects a tab again. As result there will be a state where, for example, tab index changed. What about my last question ot start topic? I know what for Rx is but... **Is there any benefit of using await emit.forEach in ObjectsBloc instead of _repository.stream.listen in ObjectsCubit to process Status.success?**

Comment: That's the whole point of a responsive UI, it does not update itself, the state manager changes the state THEN the UI reacts to the new state. Anyway, the two syntaxes _repository.stream.listen or emit.forEach are interchangeable in a Bloc. In a Cubit you don't have access to emit.forEach, because in Bloc emit is an Emitter, whereas in Cubit it is a function.